# Is there a way to solidify model only when it explodes to pieces?

Tags: modeling, animation, modifiers

If I apply Solidify modifier it changes the model look in general, I only want it to have volumetric pieces when exploded.

Comment: Can't you just keyframe the thickness value of the modifier?! (Or disable/enable the modifier with keyframes entirely.)

Comment: I didnt know I can do this. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helps. I'll post this as an answer then. Btw, you can animate the camera and screen icons by hovering with the mouse over them and pressing I. You can animate almost anything in Blender. :) Even checkboxes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can keyframe the Thickness value of the Solidify Modifier or enable/disable the modifier with keyframes.